# Making a div float left of another div when on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating this website: http://appointmentbooker.net/ and I am having a problem with my registration page for multiple devices, browsers, resolutions. I am trying to have a div appear next to certain input boxes when onfocus, and make it disappear when onblur.

For example, if you put the mouse over the password box, it will make a div appear. http://appointmentbooker.net/register.php

I need the div to appear 5 pixels to the left of certain inputs, for every resolution, and mobile, etc. It will go into random positions depending on the resolution. :(

I have tried pixels and percentages so far.

```
 <div class="jfk-bubble" id="jfk-bubble-pw2" style="visibility: hidden; left: 21%; top: 62%; opacity: 1; ">
    <p>Your password must contain a capital letter, a number, and must be atleast 8 characters long.</p>
    <div class="jfk-bubble-arrow-id jfk-bubble-arrow jfk-bubble-arrowright" style="top: 8px; ">
    </div>
    </div>
```

and this code

```
 .jfk-bubble-arrow, .jfk-bubble-arrowimplafter {
 background-image:url('images/arrow.png');
 width:20px;
 left: 289px;
 height:20px;
 background-size:cover;
 }
```

and this

```
  .jfk-bubble {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1201 !important;
 border-color: #bbb #bbb #a8a8a8;
 padding: 16px;
 width : 255px;
 line-height: 17px;
 }
```

I can get it to look great on one browser, but I think I need to force it to always appear x pixels to the left of certain inputs. Which div properties do I need to change?

Comment: can you post the script you are using to position the div or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a tooltip plugin such as jquery tooltip or this nice one ["tipsy"](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)

It will save you much time ..